# How can I print a Blank report in SSRS

Tags: forms, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a report design below.

[image: Report_Design]

I tried to delete the datasets but I get this error:

```
    tablix is in report body but the report has no dataset. 
data regions are not allowed in reports without datasets
```

I would like to print a blank report without any data in it. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to set expression for visibility on each row of tablix like below

```
=IIF(CountRows("DataSetName")>0,True,False)
```

As I don't fine any other way, I tried this and it works for me!

**Note:** *In some cases I used to create different tablix with same dataset but no grouping and just showing it on above expression. (not even details)*